# Nginx redirect https->http(reverse proxy)->port(docker container)

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

**Context**

Simple setup

- A docker container exposing 8090 as a website (node, express)
- A nginx conf exposing 80 and mapping it to localhost 8090

**Issue**

I don't have paid SSL certificate, I want end users that try to reach https to be redirected to http.

I have tried redirects, rewrite, and here below a simple listen.. without success. Browser would return 'ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR'.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443;
    ssl off;
    server_name xxxx.com;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass         "http://0.0.0.0:8090";
    }
 }
```

**Question**

Could you please advise on the cleanest way to redirect https->http(reverse proxy) ? Regards

**Edit 1**

The following config results in a browser "ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR".

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name xxxx.com;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass         "http://0.0.0.0:8090";
    }
 }


server {
       listen 443;
       server_name xxxx.com;
       rewrite ^(.*) http://$host$1 permanent;
 }
```

Comment: @wpercy thanks for your research, I reviewed and tried that solution before, couldn't make it work, see Edit 1.

Comment: If you are trying to redirect `https` to `http` without enabling SSL, you can't, it's impossible. To use `https` (even to redirect it) you need a certificate.

Comment: @RichardSmith Is there no way to smoothly redirect the end-user ?

For instance [end user browser https:// example.org] -> [he is redirected to http:// example.org and the browser shows the not-secure flag near the adress bar] ?

The issue if I enable SSL (to redirect) and put a self signed certificate is that the end user will see the full 'This site is not secure' chrome error page.

Comment: The moment the user types `https` there is an expectation that the connection will be secure and a valid certificate will be provided by your site to the browser. Wouldn't lets encrypt solve this problem?

Comment: Problem solved with lets encrypt. Thanks @RichardSmith.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using letsencrypt to get a free certificate and then either use https or redirect to http was the solution for me.

Credits to @RichardSmith

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use TCP restreaming by ngx_stream_core_module
http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_core_module.html

```
stream {
    server {
        listen 443;
        proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:80;
    }
}
```