# SSL Nginx with HTTP Docker Container pass Data from HTTP to HTTP

Tags: docker, nginx, gitlab

I'm running a Gitlab instance with Nginx and force HTTP to HTTPS. On the same server I' running a Docker container (Jetty) on Port 9000 which can only deal with HTTP. The setup ist

- Server:80 (HTTP) -> Server:443 (HTTP) - Redirect by NGINX works
- Server:443 (HTTPS) - direct NGINX call works
- Server:9000 (HTTP) - Docker container works

Now I would like to add a HTTPS call for the Docker Container through NGINX, to get:

- Server:9001 (HTTPS by NGINX) -> Server:9000 - NGINX should manage the HTTPS and pass the data to the HTTP Docker container

I have found this [description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54601559/nginx-redirect-https-httpreverse-proxy-portdocker-container) but I'm not sure how to do it correctly. Gitlab can deal with a custom  [NGINX configuration](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#inserting-custom-settings-into-the-nginx-config), so how can I deal with a crrect configuration